# Assembler 2013

Tags: ассемблер

Подскажите, нужно ли сейчас знать Assembler, в частности NASM/YASM,как это может пригодиться?

Comment: В некоторых задачах это может и пригодиться. Но это очень узкоспециализированные области. Например - работа в антивирусных компаниях.

Comment: *Необходимости* изучать ассемблер нет. Если просто интересно - то почему бы не попробовать. Но я бы посоветовал для начала привести в порядок знания по языкам высокого уровня.

Comment: Знание ассемблера, упрощает понимание языков высокого уровня.

Comment: @ildar или наоборот. По-разному бывает. Язык ассемблера желательно изучать после изучения программирования на языках высокого уровня во избежание закостенения некоторых дурных штампов в мозгу.

Comment: @alexlz, да, изучение нужно начинать с высокого уровня, хорошо подходит `Pascal`. Ассемблер помогает глубже понимать механизмы, устройство языков высокого уровня.

Comment: @ildar придётся написать, а то можно подумать, что я с Pascal'ем согласен. Что же людей на антиквариат тянет? Небось в первом классе гусиными перьями никто не агитирует писать, а изучение начинать с бейсков-паскалей -- так то и дело...

Есть scheme, есть python...

Comment: @alexlz, бейсик и лого это слишком... Можно и с современных языков начинать, таких как c++, java, delphi. Есть мнение, что сначало нужно научиться, не знаю как и написать, выработать склад ума, а всяким плюшкам можно потом научиться.

Comment: @ildar в смысле склада ума C++, java, delphi (который и есть паскаль с объедками) как раз и дают критикуемый результат.

Comment: @alexlz, а что по Вашему мнению дает не критикуемый результат?

Comment: @ildar так я уже написал: python, scheme, logo (продолжать по вкусу). С книжками sicp (Stucture and Interpretation of Computer Programs) и/или hdpd (How do Design Programs). По logo -- там свои учебники. Для лиспоидов -- произведения П. Грэма (On lisp и пр.). Имея опыт только императивного программирования трудно изучать декларативное, т.е. всякие Прологи и прочие ЭфШарпы. (пардон, на автомате набрал было "СиШарпы", что не совсем так)

Answer (score 4):

Советую лучше почитать сначала книги по архитектуре компьютера. В частности хорошая книга «Архитектура компьютера. Э. Таненбаум». Сам почитываю в свободное время.

Это фундамент, очень большой и очень крепкий. Тогда даже язык ассемблера будет казаться намного проще, чем нежели Вы начнёте сразу изучать его по специализированным книжкам и такие вопросы Вы уже не будете задавать ибо знать Вы будете всё сами.

Comment: а пригодится может например при программировании микроконтроллеров (телевизоры, микроволновки и.т.д), написание отдельных частей ОС (загрузчик например), вирусов, при дизассемблеровании (ну мало ли:)), оптимизация программы с помощью написания некоторых частей на языке ассемблера и.т.д. Но лучше читать то что я написал выше, для начала.

Comment: @dirtez поскольку идёт речь об ассемблере для x86, то микроволновые телевизоры идут лесом (т.е. промкомпьютеры на x86 возможно есть, но я про них давно не слышал).

Comment: @alexlz, пардон, Вы правы, нужно начинать с декларативного программирования.  
Когда речь пошла об "антиквариатом `pascal`е" и после сравнения гусиного пера с бейсиками, я как-то забыл про декларативное программирование.

Comment: @ildar ну не надо столь категорично. Изучать надо разные подходы и не фиксироваться на каком-то одном. Подход sicp тут кажется весьма к месту.